# why did sendmail generate this mail?

Tags: email, sendmail

Today I received this strange mail generated by sendmail to one of the recipients from the aliases file.

it is the first time we get this

```
From root@ftp.secret.net Mon Feb  2 11:35:15 2015
Received: from n1.secret.net (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by n1.secret.net (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4) with ESMTP id t12AZFMi014597
        for <sms_secret@n1.secret.net>; Mon, 2 Feb 2015 11:35:15 +0100
Received: (from root@localhost)
        by n1.secret.net (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id t12AZFTU014593
        for sms_secret@localhost; Mon, 2 Feb 2015 11:35:15 +0100
From: root <root@ftp.secret.net>
Message-Id: <201502021035.t12AZFTU014593@n1.secret.net>
Date: Mon, 02 Feb 2015 11:35:15 +0100
To: sms_secret@ftp.secret.net
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 6/20/10
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-MIME-Autoconverted: from quoted-printable to 8bit by n1.secret.net id t12AZFMi014597
```

is this normal? 
what could have caused this?

thank you 
Mario

Comment: And how exactly is it 'strange'?

Comment: just wondering what triggered that message it it was sent to root perhaps it would be okay but that it sent to an external email address startles me